# Vimeo video not working on mobile site

Tags: javascript, html, css, video, vimeo

hello I have embedded vimeo video in my website. It is showing accurately when view the website on desktop but it is not showing up on mobile. Here is the link of the website

http://bit.ly/1KtFBbq

Please any one has the idea whats wrong here.?

Answer (score 0):

You have to be a pro member for vimeo to generate mobile versions automatically

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are using flash to play the video. This is not supported in many browsers and mobile. Better user HTML  tags.

```
<video id="my_video" controls class="pull-left hideit">
     <source src="thesource.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

They are best supported. Cheers!